# Is it possible to pass values from java script to an excel file to run a function in excel and retrieve data

Tags: javascript

I'm using an excel file where it has some functions regarding a calculation.a custom made function to calculate an amount by inputting some values for 4 cell inputs.I don't know how to implement the formula by javascript, the formula is complex.is there any way that i can pass the values from my web page to the excel file and do the calculation from the excel file it self and retrieve the values and show them on the web page. what is the best solution or the approach for the given problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fear, the easiest way to do this would be to implement the formula in Javascript. As far as I know, Javascript can do everything, Excel can do.
Depending on your website's architecture you wouldn't be able to execute anything on the server and even if you do, the Excel-file doesn't do the calculations, but Excel itself does. So the file wouldn't help you without an actual Excel-installation.
On top of that, Javascript has very limited access to the users harddrive, so you wouldn't be able to download the Excel-file and execute it. It would also depend on the user to have Excel installed.
Depending on the Server you use, you could also use PHP, Java or C# for the calculation, but I think Javascript should suffice for most cases.